# Describe the local flux of this vector field $X$ on $S^2$ given by $X(v)=w_0- \langle v, w_0 \rangle v.$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let be $w_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $X: S^2 \rightarrow TS^2$ the vector field on $S^2$defined by:
$$X(v)=w_0- \langle v, w_0 \rangle v.$$
($\langle.,. \rangle$ is the standard dot product)

How can I describe the local flux of $X$?

I have written the components of $X$ and then I have found the Cauchy problem in order to find the integral curves.
The problem is that the differential equations that I' ve found are difficult to resolve.

Is there another way to find the local flux?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are your diff eqs still too difficult to solve when you consider just $w_0 = (1,0,\cdots, 0)$?  Given any $w_0$ you rotate it into being aligned with that vector, use the solution, and rotate back.

Comment: @muaddib Thanks!! yes, I can resolve them with the separation of variables.